# Excel - How to automatically convert Text URL to active hyperlinks?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file which needs to be sent to my colleagues. However, there is a column "link" which includes the text URL, the URL only can be activated when I double click this cell. How can I automatically activate these text URLs so my colleagues don't need to double click on each cell?
[image]

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Comment: Typically you only need to click once to follow a hyperlink in a cell... Is there something different about the way your cells are formatted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With inactive links in column **A**, in **B2** *(or some other column)* enter:

```
=HYPERLINK(A2,A2)
```

and copy downward.

This costs you an extra column, but it minimizes the need for "special handling".  An alternative approach might be to activate all the cell in the column with a small SendKeys macro.

Comment: Interestingly, when I try this with something like `www.google.com` I get an error stating "The address of the site is not valid. Check the address and try again". Probably because it's missing the https:// but still, weird...

Comment: @dwirony  I think the *HYPERLINK()* function needs the full URL.

Comment: @JenniferZou  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: This doesn't work